# Template instantiation with VARIANT return type

Tags: c++, templates

An explicit instantiation of a static template member function keeps failing to compile with the message `error C2785: 'at_Intermediate CUtil::convert_variant(const VARIANT &)' and '<Unknown>' have different return types`

When I make a corresponding class with non-static member functions, the compiler likes me.

```
// utility class - static methods
struct CUtil {
      template< typename at_Intermediate > static at_Intermediate convert_variant( const VARIANT &v ) ;

      template<> static VARIANT convert_variant<VARIANT >( const VARIANT &v ) { return v; } // 
      template<> static double  convert_variant<double  >( const VARIANT &v ) { return v.dblVal; }
      template<> static long    convert_variant<long    >( const VARIANT &v ) { return v.lVal  ; }
      template<> static BSTR    convert_variant<BSTR    >( const VARIANT &v ) { return v.bstrVal; }
};
```

This is a composed question:

1. Why does the compiler complain about a function "Unknown" while it's clearly known?
2. What triggers this message - it disappears when the function is made global or non-static.

EDIT:

after some useful hints from Josh: is it not allowed to explicitly instantiate template functions within the class declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you may only use explicit template specialization at namespace scope although I can't find this in the standard (but GCC says as much). The following works for me (on GCC):

```
struct CUtil {
    template< typename at_Intermediate > static at_Intermediate convert_variant( const VARIANT &v ) ;
};

template<> VARIANT CUtil::convert_variant<VARIANT >( const VARIANT &v ) { return v; }
template<> double  CUtil::convert_variant<double  >( const VARIANT &v ) { return v.dblVal; }
template<> long    CUtil::convert_variant<long    >( const VARIANT &v ) { return v.lVal  ; }
template<> BSTR    CUtil::convert_variant<BSTR    >( const VARIANT &v ) { return v.bstrVal; }
```

**EDIT** It *is* in the standard:

14.7.2.5:

> An explicit instantiation of a class or function template specialization is placed in the namespace in which the template is defined. An explicit instantiation for a member of a class template is placed in the namespace where the enclosing class is defined. *An explicit instantiation for a **member template** is placed in the namespace where the enclosing class or class template is defined.*

(All emphasis added by me.)

Comment: that's an explicit specialization tho, not instantiation. 14.7.3p2: "An explicit specialization shall be declared in the namespace of which the template is a member, or, for member templates, in the namespace of which the enclosing class or enclosing class template is a member." fits in your case :)

Comment: ah nvm, i just see it's just what the OP used too, wasn't your fault :) but maybe you can correct him about that?

Comment: it's the OriginalPoster, the guy posted the question. i think you know what the diff between the two is, but in case not: an explicit instantiation would instantiate the template for a given type in the current translation unit (so clients can use the template somewhere else without needing...

Comment: ... the template code. explicit specialization puts a different code for different types. (in your code, the difference is that you return a different member in each specialization).

Comment: @litb: In my understanding, an explicit specialization actually also *is* an instantiation. I might be wrong, though. Particularly considering that there is a separate syntax for the instantiation.

Comment: @litb: Please consider http://pastie.org/356862. AFAIK, this shouldn't work if template specialization didn't also instantiate the template.

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

```
struct CUtil {
    template< typename T > 
    static T convert_variant(const VARIANT &);
};

template<> int CUtil::convert_variant<int>(const VARIANT &);
template<> VARIANT CUtil::convert_variant<VARIANT>(const VARIANT &);
```

You can't explicitly specialize a template inside a class scope.  [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zft3014.aspx).

The wierd issue with VS2008 is that this does work.

```
struct CUtil {
    template< typename T > 
    static T convert_variant(const VARIANT &);
    template<> 
    static int convert_variant<int>(const VARIANT &);
};
```

And this:

```
struct CUtil {
    template< typename T > static void convert_variant(T);
    template<> static void convert_variant<VARIANT >(VARIANT);
};
```

Comment: ... Comeau also reacts to the explicit instantiation whithin the class body...  Defining the functions outside yields OK result.

Comment: at Codepad.org: same result (explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'struct CUtil')

Comment: your third solution should get rid of the 'static' keyword (you're not declaring there)

Comment: btw - though you didn't get to the answer, I +1'd your post 'cause it really helped me find the issue.